# For snowflakes version 2 API call, how do I retrieve the 2nd partition of the result?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For Snowflakes version 1 API call, we had the concept of pages and page numbers. For Snowflakes version 2 API, we have to provide the partition no for the data partition to be retrieved. I tried to put the partition number in the header, as a parameter and in body of the API, but I still get the first partition as response. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The partition number should be passed in the header to get the next partition as detailed here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/sql-api/handling-responses.html#retrieving-additional-partitions

```
GET /api/v2/statements/<handle>?partition=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The
`POST https://{your_accountId}.snowflakecomputing.com/api/v2/statements` will return a guid called `statementHandle`.

Plug this `statementHandle` into the subsequent
`GET /api/v2/statements/{statementHandle}?partition=2` and you will receive the `data` for that specific partition number.